# How to do a Field Resolver for a Union Type in type-graphql

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

Consider the following

The stack is type-graphql / type-orm / postgres

I am using [Single Table Inheritance](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entity-inheritance.md#single-table-inheritance) (STI) and Union Types to represent multiple feed types.

All is working nicely -- until I wanted to add a [Field Resolver](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md#field-resolvers) -- and I could not find a way to get that to work.

It looks like you can not pass an interface type to @Resolver

Some code snippits to illustrate:

The abstract top level entity

```js
@InterfaceType()
@Entity({ orderBy: { createdAt: 'DESC' } })
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: 'varchar', name: 'type' } })
export abstract class FeedItem {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  @Field()
  @Column({ nullable: false })
  type: string

  @Field(() => Customer, { nullable: true })
  @ManyToOne(
    () => Customer,
    customer => customer.feedItems,
    { onDelete: 'CASCADE' }
  )
  customer: Lazy<Customer>

  @Field(() => [FeedItemComment])
  @OneToMany(
    () => FeedItemComment,
    feedItemComment => feedItemComment.feedItem,
    { lazy: true }
  )
  comments: Lazy<FeedItemComment[]>
```

The resolver

```js
export const FeedResultUnion = createUnionType({
  name: 'FeedItemResult', // the name of the GraphQL union
  types: [AuthoredFeedItem, MilestoneFeedItem, TaskFeedItem, AssessmentFeedItem, WeeklySummaryFeedItem], // array of object types classes


@Resolver(() => FeedItem) // <---- this does not work, nor does FeedItemResult
export class FeedItemResolver {

  // would love to do something like the following, but can't ...
  @Authorized()
  @FieldResolver(() => CommentsResponse)
  async comments(@Root() feedItem: FeedItem) {
    const [feedItems, count] = await getRepository(FeedItemComment).findAndCount({
      where: {
        feedItem,
      },
      order: { createdOn: 'DESC' },
    })

    return {
      items: feedItems,
      count,
    }
  }


}


})
```

Anyone can point me to a path to victory ?!

Comment: Resolvers for interfaces should be supported as of version v0.18.0-beta.14. See [here](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/260). Resolvers for unions wouldn't be since unions don't define fields. Technically, resolvers for interface fields don't exist in GraphQL, but libraries like `type-graphql` and `graphql-tools` copy the resolver over to the resolver for each implementing type under the hood. What version are you using?

Comment: Also it would be helpful to describe what's "not working". What error are you seeing, if any? What's the expected behavior and what behavior are you actually seeing?

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems with `@FieldResolver()` I just made a change in tsconfig.json, I changed `"target": "es5"` to `"target": "es6"`

The [type-graphql documentation](https://typegraphql.com/docs/installation.html#typescript-configuration) says that you must configure the tsconfig.json for it to work

I hope I have helped